# tkz-base label only even numbers

Tags: tkz-base

Is there a way to label only the even numbers on the axes in `tkz-base`?  I can do this when the `xmin` or `ymin` is an even number using e.g. `\tkzLabelX[step=2]`, but if I do this when the minimum is odd, it labels all the odd numbers, which is almost never what I want.

Here is an example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-3, xmax=3, ymin=-5, ymax=7]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzLabelXY[step=2, orig=false]
    \tkzDrawX[right=2pt]
    \tkzDrawY[above=2pt]
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left, xshift=2, yshift=1](0,0){$0$}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I can turn off axis labeling and label the points individually, but I wonder if there's a better way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-2, xmax=2, ymin=-4, ymax=6]
    \tkzGrid(-3,-5)(3,7)
    \tkzLabelXY[step=2, orig=false]
    \tkzDrawX[right=2pt,left space=1,right space=1.5]
    \tkzDrawY[above=2pt,down space=1,up space=1.5]
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left, xshift=2, yshift=1](0,0){$0$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]